# how to get a device when I use supervisor?

Tags: webots

There are a conveyor_belt and a ur10e robot in my webots env, I set ur10e's controller as `extern`, and I want to get the kinect image which is a children on the conveyor_belt.
[ur10e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYcm.png)

[conveyor_belt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuVh2.png)

my python code is as follow:

```
from controller import Camera
from controller import PositionSensor
from controller import Supervisor

robot = Supervisor()

# Get the time step of the current world.
timestep = int(robot.getBasicTimeStep())

conveyor_belt = robot.getFromDef("CONVEYOR_BELT")
assert(conveyor_belt != None)
conveyor_kinectcolor = conveyor_belt.getDevice("kinect color")
conveyor_kinectcolor.enable(int(1000/24))
conveyor_kinectcolor.getImage()
```

but I get error with:

```
   conveyor_kinectcolor = conveyor_belt.getDevice("kinect color")
  File "/usr/local/webots/lib/controller/python27/controller.py", line 1756, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Node, name)
  File "/usr/local/webots/lib/controller/python27/controller.py", line 96, in _swig_getattr
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'getDevice'
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a device in another robot.

Alternatively, you can create a custom controller for another robot and use Emitter/Receiver to exchange commands with the supervisor.